# JDK8 with -source 1.7 [Default Methods]

Tags: java, class, javac, java-8

I have the following class.

```java
public class ZonedDateTimeToInstant {

    public static void main(final String[] args)
        throws NoSuchMethodException {

        assert ChronoZonedDateTime.class.isAssignableFrom(ZonedDateTime.class);
        final Method toInstant
            = ChronoZonedDateTime.class.getMethod("toInstant");

        final ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
        final Instant instant = now.toInstant();

        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

It just compiles fine.

```
& javac ZonedDateTimeToInstant.java
```

And it fails with `-source 1.7`.

```
& javac -source 1.7 ZonedDateTimeToInstant.java
ZonedDateTimeToInstant.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    final Instant instant = now.toInstant();
                               ^
  symbol:   method toInstant()
  location: variable now of type ZonedDateTime
1 error
1 warning
```

Is this normal? It seems that `javac` doesn't understand JDK classes with `-source` other than `1.8`.

According to [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html#BHCIJIEG), `javac` still supports various `-source release` options as previous releases did.

**Supplement**

I already know the [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) is only available in Java 8. What does it matter with `javac`?

```
$ cat Java8.java
public class Java8 {
    public void print(java.io.PrintStream out) {
        out.printf("hello world\n");
    }
}
$ javac Java8.java
$ cat Java7.java
public class Java7 {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Java8().print(System.out);
    }
}
$ javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 Java7.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning
$ java Java7
hello world
```

**Conclusion**

As @Eng.Fouad noted. The problem was that the method is a `default method` defined in an interface. `javac` seems to be catching that point.

```
$ cat Java8i.java
public interface Java8i {
    default void print(java.io.PrintStream out) {
        out.printf("hello world\n");
    }
}
$ javac Java8i.java
$ cat Java8c.java
public class Java8c implements Java8i {
}
$ javac Java8c.java
$ cat Java7i.java
public class Java7i {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Java8c().print(System.out);
    }
}
$ javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 Java7i.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Java7i.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    new Java8c().print(System.out);
                ^
  symbol:   method print(PrintStream)
  location: class Java8c
1 error
1 warning
```

**`javac` should've told me more helpfully.**

Comment: You can use the [Three Ten Backport](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) if you really need to use it in JDK 1.7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>This is a new Time/Date API which is introduced in Java 8. That's why it does not compile with Java 7.</strike>

`toInstant()` is a default method, whereas `-source 1.7` doesn't support default methods (Java 8's new feature).

Comment: I know Time/Date API is newly included in Java 8. What's about it with `javac`?

Comment: @JinKwon It might be because `toInstant()` is a default method, whereas `-source 1.7` doesn't support default methods.

Answer (score 3):

This was produced because of a bug in javac. Related bugs are: [JDK-8029240](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029240) and [JDK-8030855](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8030855). Both issues are already fixed. If you get a recent version of JDK8 or clone the last compiler version from [langtools dev repo](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/langtools), you should be able to compile your code.